# Wrong index been peeked

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, mysql-5.7

I have an index that filters 99% of the table i.e. `ix_magic_composite` (for that query arguments).
When I add another `or` filter it chooses the wrong index, i.e. `fTS` even if I create an index that starts with that field it still choose the wrong index. Run times are 20s vs 3s to the better index. `ix_magic_composite` index returns (initial filter) for both SQLs around 10 rows out of millions, while `fTS` returns millions back.

Kind of clueless. It looks to me as the statistics aren't giving the engine the right picture with all those columns combined.

I simplified the table, it has a lot more columns and indexes.

SQL w/ good plan:

```
select *
from tblExample
where 1=1
and status = 'okay'
and textCol > ''
and insrBLN = 1
and (magic is NULL or magic = '')
and (itemId is NULL or itemId = '')
and fTS > '2020-01-01'
and fTS > '2020-01-01'
order by fTS
limit 50

+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type        | possible_keys                                    | key                 | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tblExample | NULL       | ref_or_null | textCol,status,textCol_4,ix_magic_composite,fTS  | ix_magic_composite  | 53      | const | 5892974 |     0.24 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

SQL w/ bad plan:

```
select *
from tblExample
where 1=1
and status = 'okay'
and textCol > ''
and insrBLN = 1
and (magic is NULL or magic = '' or magic = 'retry')
and (itemId is NULL or itemId = '' or itemId = 'retry')
and fTS > '2020-01-01'
and fTS > '2020-01-01'
order by fTS
limit 50

+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                   | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tblExample | NULL       | range | textCol,status,textCol_4,ix_magic_composite,fTS | fTS     | 5       | NULL | 6271587 |    0.18  | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------    ----+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblExample` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fTS` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  `textCol` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insrBLN` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `itemId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `magic` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_magic_composite` (`itemId`,`magic`,`fTS`,`insrBLN`),
  KEY `fTS` (`fTS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14391289 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**EDIT**

We have refactor the code so the query looks like:

```
select *
from tblExample
where 1=1
and status = 'okay'
and textCol > ''
and insrBLN = 1
and (retry = '' or (retry='retry' and retryDT < now() - interval 1 day))
and fTS > '2020-01-01'
order by fTS
limit 50
```

The issue was NOT sorted (also tried different columns order in the index).
It looks like it chooses the right index only if I remove the order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor didn't work.
I decided to move to `UNION ALL` which gives the same results as `use index` or `force index`. I choose that approach since it will not require any code change if the index gets dropped or renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding OR clauses makes it more difficult to estimate how well the index will filter. One solution is to add a generated always column that calculates whether the predicates for magic and itemId are satisfied, and index that:

```
CREATE TABLE tblExample (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fTS timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  status varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  textCol varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  insrBLN tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  itemId varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
  magic varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
  retry tinyint GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
      ( case when  (magic is NULL or magic = '' or magic = 'retry') 
               AND (itemId is NULL or itemId = '' or itemId = 'retry')
             then 1 
             else 0
        end
      ) STORED,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_magic_composite` (retry,`fTS`,`insrBLN`),
  KEY `fTS` (`fTS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14391289 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The query can then be changed to:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tblExample t
WHERE status = 'okay'
and textCol > ''
and insrBLN = 1
and retry
and fTS > '2020-01-01'
and fTS > '2020-01-01'  -- can be removed I assume
order by fTS
limit 50;
```

The correct solution is probably to fix the data model, but that may not be possible.

Comment: Comments [archived](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112438/discussion-on-answer-by-lennart-wrong-index-been-peeked).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things getting in the way of efficiency:

- `OR`.  Even "ref_or_null" is less than optimal.  To start with, can you avoid having both `''` and `NULL` for the column?  That is, clean up the data and the processing to use *either* `''` *or* `NULL`.  That way, you won't need to test for both.
- Because of `(itemId is NULL or itemId = '' or itemId = 'retry')`, I recommend picking `NULL`, not `''`, so that "ref_or_null_ can be used.
- As you already discovered, `UNION` (preferably `ALL`) is a workaround for `OR`.  Alas, that gets messy with more than one `OR`.
- There are multiple "ranges" (textcol, fTS, retryDT).  Only one can be effectively used.  And, all too often, the Optimizer cannot correctly pick which one to focus on.
- The Optimizer prefers to "filter" the data (via `WHERE`) and not worry about sorting (`ORDER BY`).  But when the `WHERE` clause gets too complex, the Optimizer may abandon `WHERE` and simply focus on `ORDER BY`.  Your second query is an example of this.
- Actually that second query can be improved by changing `INDEX(fTS)` to `INDEX(status, insrBLN, fTS)`.  That way, it can do some of the filtering before sorting; then finish filtering as it walks through the rows.
- Then, after picking either `''` or `NULL`, that index can be further changed to
  `INDEX(status, insrBLN, magic, itemId, fTS)`.
- Note that I have the `=` tests first in the `INDEX`, and the "range" and/or `ORDER BY` column (`FTS`) last.  (The ordering of the `=` columns does not matter.)
- The existence of a second "range" (`textcol > ''`) test prevents having a single index that handles both the filtering and the sorting.  (I don't think there is any workaround.)
- The order of columns in `ix_magic_composite` is suboptimal for all of the queries you presented.  The important thing is that `insrBLN` (tested with `=`) needs to be before `FTS` (a range), not after.
- When using `UNION`, you will need to devise an optimal index for *each* component of the `UNION`.